# Post request working fine in cURL but not in Android Volley

Tags: java, android, authentication, curl, android-volley

This cURL command is working fine when I run it on my terminal:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:
>   Basic uname:pass123" -d '{"userName":"uname","password":"pass123"}'
>   "http://mysite123.com/api/Login"

Now, I am trying to use Android Volley to send this post request. The code is as follows:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url = "http://mysite123.com/api/Login";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){

            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("userName", "uname");
            params.put("password", "pass123");
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers=new HashMap<String,String>();

            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "utf-8");
            String creds = String.format("%s:%s","uname","pass123");
            String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Authorization", auth );
            return headers;
        }

    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

But it gives me error in stackTrace as :

> 09-03 07:46:43.823 17712-17918/com.ankitshubham97.gpsmonitoring E/Volley: [108117] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://mysite123.com/api/Login
>   09-03 07:46:43.833 17712-17712/com.ankitshubham97.gpsmonitoring E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
>   09-03 07:46:43.843 17712-17712/com.ankitshubham97.gpsmonitoring W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
>   09-03 07:46:43.853 17712-17712/com.ankitshubham97.gpsmonitoring W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
>   09-03 07:46:43.853 17712-17712/com.ankitshubham97.gpsmonitoring W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)

What could be the problem? Or any method of directly sending the curl command from android?

**EDIT:** I even used https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ to convert the above cURL command to php code and the php runs fine too. I wonder what's wrong with Volley!

Comment: I tried your curl command but its giving the same response 405 Method not Allowed - DOSarrest Internet Security

Comment: That is because I have given false url, username and password here instead of the genuine ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Postman helped me. So, the problem was that `'{"userName":"uname","password":"pass123"}'` was to be sent as raw form with json format and in body(not as param). So, I used this method:

```
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
```

I have defined the `requestBody` before as:

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try{

        jsonBody.put("userName", "uname");
        jsonBody.put("password", "pass123");
    }
    catch (JSONException e){

    }

    final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
```